# SQL query with order by in groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I'm looking for a way to order my result in a correct way for a SQL Server 2019 query.

I have the table 'ItemCode' that is 4 numbers long and the first number stands for a group as part of the item code structure.

Now we also have 'ItemCode' with 5 numbers and I want those to be shown in the block of '1' if the first characters matches, same for 2 and so on.

Default list is something like this:

```
1010
2010
3010
10010
20010
30010
```

I want the output to be:

```
1010
10010
2010
20010
3010
30010
```

Grouped by the first number and then sorted ascending in that 'group'
How can I make this work?

Comment: which database system are you using. simply convert it to char

Comment: Are those numbers stored as `int` or `varchar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specific on which database you are dealing with... Sql-Server, MySql, Postgres, etc.   Also, what is the data type as stored.. integer, character.  If integer, you need to convert to a string and get the leading character.  But then need to consider the total length -- yes, you appear to only have 4 or 5 digits, but if any other future lengths, so you dont falsely get something like

```
1345
128
18294
223
21
289840
```

just because the first digit is pre-grouped consideration.  I would think you are looking to have them by value low to high such as:

```
128
1345
18294
21
223
289840
```

Modified based on language (sql-server here) and data type column (assuming an integer column type, so I am pre-converting to a varchar)

```
select 
        left( convert( varchar(6), ItemCode), 1 ) LeadingDigit, 
        len( convert( varchar(6), ItemCode)) NumDigits, 
        convert( varchar(6), ItemCode) IntAsChar, 
        ItemCode
    from 
        YourTable
    order by
        1, 2, ItemCode
```

Here, the order by is based on the ordinal column of the query, just so you could run and see context of the output.

```
select 
        ItemCode 
    from 
        YourTable
    order by
        left( convert( varchar(6), ItemCode), 1 ), 
        len( convert( varchar(6), ItemCode)), 
        ItemCode
```

Now, if your column is already character, just strip out the conversion

```
select 
        ItemCode 
    from 
        YourTable
    order by
        left( ItemCode, 1 ), 
        len( ItemCode), 
        ItemCode
```

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my sorting issue.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column

FROM table
order by left(string(column),1)

Answer (score 0):

```
`select 
i.codev
from 
    itemcode i 
order by
    left(i.codev,1)
    ,SUBSTRING(i.codev,3,1) desc 
;`
```

Column type: varchar